# How can I use DateDiff in a seperate Crystal Reports formula?

Tags: crystal-reports, datediff, crystal-reports-2008

I have a formula which uses DateDiff to find out the difference between two dates and excludes the weekends.

I'd like to then use that DateDiff in another formula to calculate averages based on and if/then criteria.

When I put average({date diff formula}) I receive an error of "Invalid Argument was encountered"

I can't use the date diff formula in any formula I try to use it in, is there a reason for this?

Comment: Worked for me, show us your formulas? I used
DateTest1: DateDiff('d',*datetime column*,today)
DateTest2: If @DateTest1 > 5 Then 'yes' Else 'No'
Is this comparable?

Comment: DateDiff returns an integer (or rational number depending on your parameter choice, I used 'd' for days), so make sure your logic treats it like a single number, not a date itself

Comment: Ah - reread your question. My second comment applies. Average(*DateDiffFormula*) is the same as saying Average(*SingleNumber*), eg Average(5) which doesn't make sense. Try using a running total, selecting average, and putting in your group footer

Comment: This is my DateDiff formula: datediff("d",{@Original Request Date},{@shipdate})
-datediff("ww",{@Original Request Date},{@shipdate},crSaturday)
-datediff("ww",{@Original Request Date},{@shipdate},crSunday)

Comment: I'm trying to make a formula if {shipment type} = 'x' then average{datediff} when I enter the datediff formula in this formula is when I get the error

Comment: See answer below, it applies. You can Evaluate by a formula, put your if/then statement in there. Average(*RealRationalNumber*) doesn't make sense, you need to take the Average of multiple values, ie multiple rows,  thus the average needs to be in the group summary for the group summarizing the rows you wish to average. Try using the running total example shown below, post back with what you've tried and your results

Answer (score 0):

Example DateDiff formula:

`DateDiff('d',*datecolumn*,today)`

Then pass that thru into your running total, eg:

[image: Example Running Total for an Average]

Make a grouping in your group expert for the set you wish to summarize with an average, select that group in the Evaluate section and, if desired, in the Reset as well.

Let me know if this isn't quite it for you, good luck!